# slice assignment slower using memoryview (Python 3.5.0)

Tags: python, python-3.5, memoryview

I have a large bytearray x and want to assign a slice of it to a slice of another bytearray y

```
x = bytearray(10**7) #something else in practice
y = bytearray(6*10**6)
y[::6] = x[:2*10**6:2]
```

I figured using memoryview would be faster, and indeed

```
memoryview(x)[:2*10**6:2]
```

is very fast.  However,

```
y[::6] = memoryview(x)[:2*10**6:2]
```

takes 5 times as long as `y[::6] = x[:2*10**6:2]`

1. Am I missing something, or is this slowdown a bug in Python?
2. What is the fastest way to do this in Python (a) if I want to repeatedly assign a known number of 0's, and (b) in general?

Comment: I would look into using numpy for fast operations on large numerical arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slowdown is not so much a bug, but that `memoryview` and the buffer protocol are still relatively new to and are poorly optimised. The underlying code to `y[::6] = memoryview(x)[:2*10**6:2]` creates a contiguous copy of the `bytearray` before copying it over. Meaning it will be slower than directly creating and assigning a normal slice of the `bytearray`. Indeed, in this particular instance (on my machine), using a `memoryview` is closer in speed to using `y[::6] = islice(x, None, 2*10**6, 2)` than direct assignment.

`numpy` has existed for much longer and is much better optimised for the types of operations you are interested in doing.

Using ipython:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np; from itertools import islice

In [2]: x = bytearray(10**7)

In [3]: y = bytearray(6*10**6)

In [4]: x_np = np.array(x)

In [5]: y_np = np.array(y)

In [6]: %timeit y[::6] = memoryview(x)[:2*10**6:2]
100 loops, best of 3: 10.9 ms per loop

In [7]: %timeit y[::6] = x[:2*10**6:2]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.65 ms per loop

In [8]: %timeit y[::6] = islice(x, None, 2*10**6, 2)
10 loops, best of 3: 22.9 ms per loop

In [9]: %timeit y_np[::6] = x_np[:2*10**6:2]
1000 loops, best of 3: 911 µs per loop
```

The last two have the added benefit of having very little memory overhead.